# What’s the difference between Next.js rewrites and HTTP proxy middleware?

Tags: node.js, express, proxy, next.js

Just trying to figure out the differences between Next.js rewrites and setting up a proxy with http-proxy-middleware. I have a Next.js project with some proxies setup in the API and wondering if I can swap out the proxies for rewrites.

What are the differences, if any? Is there something I’m missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`rewrites` are a convenient way of proxying requests without having to setup your own logic in a server - Next.js handles it for you instead.

Just like `http-proxy-middleware`, they allow you to map an incoming request path to a different destination. The main difference is that `rewrites` are also applied to client-side routing, when using Next.js' built-in router (through `next/link` or `next/router`) to navigate between pages.

From the [`rewrites`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/rewrites) documentation:

> Rewrites act as a URL proxy and mask the destination path, making it
> appear the user hasn't changed their location on the site.
>
> (...) Rewrites are applied to client-side routing, a `<Link href="/about">`
> will have the rewrite applied in the above example.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, thank you for your answer. I understand the differences now.